# Creating a Highchart with multiple series from a JSON file

Tags: json, highcharts

I am trying to create a highchart importing data from a JSON file I have on the server. The JSON file is formatted as follows:

```
[
[1583595673000,21.3,45.0,12.7,66.0,11.4,6.5,0.0,1005.8,7222,1],
[1583595973000,21.3,45.0,12.6,67.0,11.6,6.6,0.0,1005.7,6145,1],
[1583596273000,21.3,45.0,12.6,68.0,11.4,6.8,0.0,1005.7,6211,1],
[1583596573000,21.2,44.0,12.5,68.0,11.3,6.8,0.0,1005.6,6418,1],
[1583596873000,21.2,44.0,12.5,68.0,10.6,6.8,0.0,1005.6,5055,1],
[1583597173000,21.2,45.0,12.4,68.0,11.1,6.7,0.0,1005.5,8063,1],
[1583597473000,21.2,45.0,12.4,68.0,11.4,6.7,0.0,1005.5,5779,1],
[1583597773000,21.2,45.0,12.4,68.0,10.9,6.7,0.0,1005.5,3800,1],
[1583598073000,21.2,45.0,12.3,68.0,10.8,6.6,0.0,1005.5,3250,1],
[1583598373000,21.1,45.0,12.2,68.0,10.2,6.5,0.0,1005.2,2573,1],
[1583598673000,21.1,45.0,12.2,68.0,11.2,6.5,0.0,1005.5,2512,1],
[1583598973000,21.1,45.0,12.1,67.0,10.0,6.2,0.0,1005.2,2710,1],
[1583599273000,21.1,46.0,12.1,66.0,10.5,5.9,0.0,1005.4,2338,1],
[1583599573000,21.2,46.0,12.1,65.0,10.6,5.7,0.0,1005.2,2320,1],
[1583599873000,21.2,46.0,12.2,64.0,10.0,5.6,0.0,1005.2,2606,1],
[1583600173000,21.2,47.0,12.2,64.0,10.2,5.6,0.0,1005.3,3142,1],
[1583600473000,21.3,49.0,12.2,64.0,10.0,5.6,0.0,1005.1,2916,1],
[1583600773000,21.4,49.0,12.2,63.0,10.2,5.4,0.0,1005.1,2663,1],
[1583601073000,21.5,50.0,12.2,63.0,10.4,5.4,0.0,1005.2,2089,0],
[1583601373000,21.5,52.0,12.2,63.0,9.5,5.4,0.0,1005.1,2334,0]
]
```

Each line contains the datestamp followed by all the different data values

The code of my chart is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/xrange.js"></script>

    <div id="chart1_container" style="height: 600px"></div>

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var chart1;

$(document).ready(function() {

chart1 = new Highcharts.chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'chart1_container',
    type: 'line',
    marginLeft: 87,
    zoomType: 'x',
    events: {
            load: getChart1data
        },
    title: {
      text: 'TEST',
    },
  },
  xAxis: {
    //today

    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
      format: '{value:%b %e}'
    },
  },
  yAxis: {
    labels: {
      format: '{value} In'
    },
  },

  series: [{
        name: 'First Series',
        data: [],
    },{
        name: 'Second Series',
        data: [],
    },{
        name: 'Third Series',
        data: [],
    },{
        name: 'Fouth Series',
        data: [],
    }],
  plotOptions: {
    line: {
      lineWidth: 1,
      states: {
        hover: {
          lineWidth: 2
        }
      },
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      },
    },
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
});
});

function getChart1data() 
{
    $.ajax({
    url: 'data/7days_highchart.json',
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data) 
    {
           console.log(data);
           chart1.series[0].setData(data);
           chart1.series[1].setData(data);
           chart1.series[2].setData(data);
           chart1.series[3].setData(data);
    },      
    });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This produces a graph but all four series are identical, how do I adapt the code so that each series refers to a different dataset?

I've created a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ashenshugar/vw5a2431/ but it doesn't work as I can't emulate the external JSON file...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the code for the solution above as I do not necessarily want to display data from consecutive entries.

```
 function getChart1data() 
    {
        $.ajax({
        url: 'data/7days_highchart.json',
        datatype: "json",
        success: function(data) 
        {
               console.log(data);
               chart1.series[0].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[1]]));
               chart1.series[1].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[2]]));
               chart1.series[2].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[5]]));
               chart1.series[3].setData(data.map(el => [el[0], el[6]]));
        },      
        });
    }
```

Comment: Here is a link tothe fully working version on jsfiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/ashenshugar/716jx4n9/](http://jsfiddle.net/ashenshugar/716jx4n9/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to correctly map your data, for example:

```
function getChart1data() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'data/7days_highchart.json',
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        chart1.series[i].setData(
          data.map(el => [el[0], el[i + 1]])
        );
      }
    }
  });
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4943/

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly. I've modified your code slightly as I don't necessarily want to display consecutive entries.